# add an item to a sales order in Netsuite suitescript

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I'm trying to figure out the code behind looking at a new Sales Order that has an item called "**Repair**" and add a second item called "**Repair Cost**" before User submit.  I'm a bit lost and I welcome any help that can be given.  I would like this script to be in Javascript and I will attach it to the Sales Order form in Netsuite to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one sample solution:

We will still assume that the items internal ids are Repair = 100 and Repair Cost = 200

```
function recalc(type)
{
    if(type == 'item')
    {
        var itemId = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item'); //Get the Item ID
        if(itemId == 100) //Repair Cost
        {
                //Insert item
                nlapiSelectNewLineItem('item');
                nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item', 200); //Repair Cost
                nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', 1);
                nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'amount', '0.00');
                nlapiCommitLineItem('item');
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Deploy this as client-side code and make sure that the function is Recalc.

To learn more about client side script: [https://system.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/Output/Help/SuiteFlex/SuiteScript/SSScriptTypes_ClientScripts.html#1016773](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/Output/Help/SuiteFlex/SuiteScript/SSScriptTypes_ClientScripts.html#1016773)

Comment: I really appreciate your work on this but I get this error:  An unexpected error occurred in a script running on this page.

recalc (recalc)
customform

UNEXPECTED_ERROR (id=he7iqv95g6hfigxhujc7)
An unexpected error has occurred. Please click <a href="javascript:window.open('/app/crm/support/nlcorpsupport.nl?l=T&type=bug&ticket=he7iqv95g6hfigxhujc7', 'Error','scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,width=800,height=700');void(0)">here</a> to notify support and provide your contact information.  I have this listed in the recalc function on the form.

Comment: Nevermind.  That error is because of the extra LineItemValue code I added.  All good.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is to get the internal id of the item "Repair" and "Repair Cost".

In this example, let's assumed that the internal id of Repair = 100 and Repair Cost = 200

Here is th code:

```
function afterSubmit(type)
{
    if(type == 'create' || type == 'edit')
    {
        var record = nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId()); //Load the record

        //Loop to all sublist item
        var count = record.getLineItemCount('item');
        for(var i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            var item = record.getLineItemValue('item', 'item', i); //This will return the internal id of the item
            if(item == 100) //Item is equal to 100; insert one item
            {
                record.insertLineItem('item', i);
                record.setLineItemValue('item', 'item', i, 200); //Repair Cost internal id
                record.setLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', i, 1); //You should put some quantity; depending on your account setup all required fields should be set here.
            }
        }

        //Submit the changes
        nlapiSubmitRecord(record, true);
    }
}
```

To understand the suitescript API and the fields exposed to sales order check on this Netsuite helpguide:

https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/RecordsBrowser/2012_2/Records/salesorder.html

Comment: So I put this script in my Netsuite account and added it to my Sales Order form and I got the error:  An unexpected error occurred in a script running on this page. additemtorepairSO.js(fieldChange) customform.  JS_EXCEPTION ReferenceError additemtorepairSO is not defined.   Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm wondering if this has to do with any required fields.  I'll mess with the required fields and reply back.

Comment: How did you deploy it? This should be deployed as user-event script in sales order record.

Comment: I see so you wanted to do it in client-side. Add a new line item with specified sku whenever a specific sku is added. The code that I showed is for user-event script. I'll get back to you with a client-code.

Comment: "additemtorepairSO.js(fieldChange) customform. JS_EXCEPTION ReferenceError additemtorepairSO" - With regards to this error, it means that your function is not defined in the deployment.

Comment: Thanks,  I appreciate it.  I forgot to mention this would run client side.  :)